# Microsoft Azure with Kubernetes and Helm "The maximum number of data disks allowed to be attached to a VM of this size is 4."

Tags: azure, kubernetes, vhd, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run different helm charts and I keep running into this error. It's much more cost effective for me to run 3-4 cheaper nodes than 1 or 2 very expensive nodes that can have more disks attached to them.

Is there a way to configure kubernetes or helm to have a disk attach limit or to set the affinity of one deployment to a particular node?

It's very frustrating that all the deployments try to attach to one node and then run out of disk attach quota.

Here is the error:

> Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="OperationNotAllowed"
>   Message="The maximum number of data disks allowed to be attached to a
>   VM of this size is 4."

Comment: Well... what size VM are you trying to use? Azure only allows 2 disks per core (same as it's always been), and that rule cannot be changed (and has nothing to do with kubernetes/helm). Also, just curious - what size disks are you trying to attach?

Comment: Numbers of disks is determined by the VM size, we can't change it, it is by design.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to configure kubernetes or helm to have a disk attach
>   limit or to set the affinity of one deployment to a particular node?

For now, ACS k8s provision PVC based on Azure managed disks or blob disks, so the limit is the number of VM disks.

For now, Azure does not support change the limit about number of VM disks. About VM size and max data disks, we can find the limit here:
[image]

More information about limit, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-memory).

By the way, the disk maximum capacity is **2TB**, maybe we can extend it to 2TB.

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.